# how calculate new data from specific date in R

Tags: r

I have below data table in R

```
"country","date","confirmed"
"Afghanistan",2020-01-22,1
"Afghanistan",2020-01-23,3
"Afghanistan",2020-01-24,5
...
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-28,100
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-29,102
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-30,110
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-01,122
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-02,130
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-03,133
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-04,150
```

There is increasing "Confirmed" cases values for each country.
I would like to make  new table for  last 7 days.
So it will check last date value in table (in my case 2020-07-04 ) and subtract -7 days as start point.
Then it will recalculate all Confirmed values from this point.

e.g. new data for Zimbabwe will be>

e.g. Starting point for Zimbabwe is : 2020-06-28, 100
so it will subtract from all next values -100

```
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-28,0
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-29,2
"Zimbabwe",2020-06-30,10
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-01,22
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-02,30
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-03,33
"Zimbabwe",2020-07-04,50
```

Any idea how to solve this logic ?

Thank you

FYI: here is my current website https://webcovid19.live/

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` here is one way to solve this :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(country, date) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  filter(date > max(date) - 7) %>%
  mutate(confirmed = confirmed - first(confirmed))
```